# advanced sql update command

Tags: sql, t-sql

Lets say I have a table that has a bit column named `Active`.  By default, the column will contain a value of false for every row except one. When I choose to use a gridview to update a new row and have its 'Active' column change from false to true...

How can I modify the following update command to update all previous rows to false when a new row is to be set to true. ( I only want to have one row be set to active(true) at a time in this table).

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [RbSpecials] 
                  SET [Name] = @Name, 
                      [Description] = @Description, 
                      [Active] = @Active 
                WHERE [ID] = @ID">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE [RbSpecials] 
SET 
    [Name] = @Name, 
    [Description] = @Description, 
    [Active] = @Active WHERE [ID] = @ID

UPDATE [RbSpecials] 
SET 
    [Active] = 0 WHERE [ID] != @ID
```

You could create a stored procedure that does this and then just pass `@Name`, `@Description` and `@ID`.

Comment: You *can* do it with one command (see my answer) but this is a much better solution.

Comment: Dustin I modified the query you gave me to check if the Active is already set to 1, if it is not it wont remove active status from any other rows. UPDATE [RbSpecials] SET [Active] =0 WHERE [ID] != @ID and @Active = 1

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [RbSpecials]
SET [Active] CASE WHEN [ID] = @ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Sorry for possible mistakes, I have not been working with sql server long ago, but I hope you'll get the idea

Also in case of optimisation this `WHERE` clause can be added

```
WHERE [ID] = @ID OR [Active] = 1
```

Comment: Almost got it, except for a missing `=`.  `SET [ACTIVE] = CASE...`  Not bad for being away from SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you could do it like this:

```
UPDATE [RbSpecials] SET 
    [Name] = case when [ID] = @ID then @Name else [Name] end,
    [Description] = case when [ID] = @ID then @Description else [Description] end,
    [Active] = case when [ID] = @ID then 1 else 0 end
FROM [RbSpecials]
```

But it would be more efficient (I have not profiled, but it seems intuitive) and definitely far more readable to do this in two statements, per Dustin Laine's answer.

Comment: Interesting approach, as you said not as efficient but an alternative.